# Key Entry Sequence from file -- PHP

Tags: php, key, sequence, writer, reader

So, I am teaching myself php and I managed to find some pretty basic coding problems to help practice. The one that I am stuck on seems like it has a simple solution. I am using code from a previous problem (a Entry Sequence Create) and turn it into a Key Sequence Create. Basically, the code needs to read in a file, find where a key value belongs in the order of the list, and then insert the record in its respected position.

```
<?php
//read current file
$studentArray = file("student.txt"); 
echo "Create Key Sequence Student File\n";
echo "Enter ID: ";
$id = rtrim(fgets(STDIN));
echo "Enter FN: ";
$fn = rtrim(fgets(STDIN));
echo "Enter LN: ";
$ln = rtrim(fgets(STDIN));
echo "Enter Major: ";
$maj = rtrim(fgets(STDIN));
echo "Enter Credit Hours: ";
$cHours = rtrim(fgets(STDIN));
//put them in a string
$studentString = "$id".':'."$fn".':'."$ln".':'."$maj".':'."$cHours\n";
//add the string to the array and write array to file
$studentArray[] = $studentString;  
$studentString = implode("",$studentArray);
file_put_contents("student.txt",$studentString);
?>
```

I have no idea what to do. The text I've found doesn't include anything about a Key Sequence Create formula

```
10000:Bill:Smith:CPSC:34
10010:Jan:Wilson:CPSC:0
10020:Sue:Sweet:ENGR:231
10030:Li:Chan:BIOL:64
10040:Luis:Gonzales:MATH:90
```

Is the contents of the value we are reading from. The key we use 10015 (the value id). The code should be able to read over the list and determine where 10015 fits in and then insert the information from the STDIN accordingly.

Comment: do you want eventually to get a file with rows that ordered by id?

Comment: It's already ordered technically. The code should take the $id the user inputs, search for it's place in the file, convert the array to a string, then insert where it belongs.

Comment: can you show any row or few rows of initial file "student.txt" for example?

Comment: That's what the second block of 'code' is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why search for it's place?  Just insert and sort:

```
$studentString = "$id".':'."$fn".':'."$ln".':'."$maj".':'."$cHours\n";
$studentArray[] = $studentString;  
sort($studentArray);
file_put_contents("student.txt",$studentArray);
```

Also, no need for `implode()`, as `file_put_contents()` will do this for you.

Comment: and what if in future the crucial input value will be $cHours, not value id ?

Comment: Planning for the future, a database.

Comment: Will this sort by the first column (the list of $id's) numerically? Is there way to specify the sort function life in java? I am very new to php haha

Comment: This will sort by the entire line which effectively sorts by the id if they are unique.  To sort by others, this entire method is not good you need a database.  http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php